# Debugar aplicação .net core no docker no windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, debug, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Eu preciso gerar uma aplicação em um container docker, mas o meu computador está com o SO do windows 7.

Instalei o Docker Toolbox, e dentro do bash proprio dele consigo rodar o container hello world, mas o visual studio 2017 não reconhece que o docker esta instalado.

Gostaria de saber como resolver.

Comment: É interessante saber se há alguma solução, é possível que não haja.

Comment: Então, infelismente eu acho que não há mesmo